# How read data from csv file in locust performance test scripts?

Tags: locust

I am trying to read the data from csv file that contails 1 row and 5  column using the following code

```
def __init__(self):
        super(data, self).__init__()
        global data
        if (data == None):
            with open('var.csv', 'r') as l:
                reader = csv.reader(l)
                data = list(reader)
def on_start(self):
            if len(data) > 0:
                self.my_value = data.pop()
```

My output is ('sample') and I want it to be sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line from `self.my_value = data.pop()` to `self.my_value = data.pop()[0]`.

But you could also use locust plugins csv reader: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/csvreader_ex.py

Comment: good place to find extra tools to work with Locust.